# Speeding up a very large Bing Maps polyline based layer

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am writing a Bing Map based Universal App for Windows Phone and Windows 8 that shows some quite large map layers.

Writing the initial app was no problem (the tutorial I followed is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbrundritt/archive/2014/06/24/how-to-make-use-of-maps-in-universal-apps.aspx), however I now am experiencing major problems rendering a layer that contains thousands of polylines, with tens of thousands of co-ordinates.

The data is just too big - on Windows 8.1, the map crashes the application, while on Windows Phone 8.1, the layer takes a very long time to render.

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/04/23/visualize-large-complex-data-with-local-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-windows-store-apps-c.aspx, I should speed it up by converting it to a local tile layer, however, the program mentioned in the article (MapCruncher) requires a PNG as input. The question is, how do I convert my map data to a PNG? I can have the data as a shapefile, KML file, or a CSV file. Is there another way I should be doing this? I know I can do this via Geoserver, however my app has to have offline support and so cannot download from the web server the appropriate files as needed.

If anyone has an other ways I could approach this speed issue with large layers, then that would be greatly appreciated. I am aware that I can speed up rendering of a layer in Bing Maps via quadtrees, however most of what I have found is theoretical. If anyone has some code I can plug in to this, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I solved this problem before, by making sure I only add polylines to the map if they are actually visible on the map (using bounding boxes), and not adding polylines that are to small to notice given the current zoom level. Just subscribe to the map's events to detect changes in the view, and add or remove polylines accordingly.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Do you have any sample code available that uses this approach?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it was work for a client and I don't have access to the source any more. But it is rather straightforward actually. Just find out what part of the map is showing, both initially and through events when the view changes. Than remove polylines that aren't visible, and add polylines that are. Organizing your polylines in a quadtree will improve the performance, but I'm not sure it is even required. Do calculate and cache their bounding boxes upfront though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local tile layers are fine if you only have data in a small area, or only want to show the data for a few zoom levels. Otherwise the number of tiles grows drastically and will make your app huge. If your data changes regularly, or you want to support all zoom levels of the map you should store your data on a server and expose it as a dynamic tile layer. A dynamic tile layer is a web service that generates a till on demand from your data. You can add caching to the tiles for performance. This is the best way to handle large data sets and one I have used a lot. In fact I have a demo here: http://onsbingmapsdemo.cloudapp.net/ This data set consists of 175,000 complex polygons that equates to about 2GB of data.

I have an old blog post on how to do this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/dynamic-tile-layers-in-the-bing-maps-silverlight-control/

If you prefer working with MVC you might find these project useful:
https://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/

https://dataconnector.codeplex.com/

Comment: And if data don't change, you can use Mapbox studio (or their previous version) or any tile server to render the data in a pyramid of tile images.

Comment: @rbrundritt Thanks for the detailed post. I was hoping I wouldn't have to go server side, however the code you posted was very helpful for me to understand how tile layers are generated. Thanks!